Twilio verification check test number
Does twilio offer a test number for their verification check endpoint? I need twilio to respond successfully to a verification check using dummy information. The closest I've gotten is +15017122661 from their verificationCheck documentation, but that returns as an invalid code submitted.
Here's the endpoint I'm using:
https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/${verifySid}/VerificationCheck
The function I'm testing:
export async function submitOtp(phone: string, code: string): Promise<boolean> {
  let submitResponse = false;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/${verifySid}/VerificationCheck`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': authHeader,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        'To': phone,
        'Code': code,
      }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    submitResponse = data.status === 'approved';
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  return submitResponse;
}

And the test I'm using:
import '$std/dotenv/load.ts';

import { parseArgs } from '$std/cli/parse_args.ts';
import { submitOtp } from '$app/twilio/twilio.ts';

/*
Run with:
deno test -A tests/SubmitOtp.test.ts

Test with alternative phone number:
deno run -A tests/SubmitOtp.test.ts --recipient "+000000000"
*/

const DEFAULT_RECIPIENT_PHONE = '+15017122661'; // This number will return a 404 and fail the test.
const DEFAULT_VERIFICATION_CODE = '123456'; // This code is invalid when matched with the default phone number.
// To pass the test, verify a real number and code using SendOtp.test.ts.

const testArguments = parseArgs(Deno.args, {
  string: ['recipient', 'code'],
  default: {
    'recipient': DEFAULT_RECIPIENT_PHONE,
    'code': DEFAULT_VERIFICATION_CODE,
  },
});

async function submitOtpTest() {
  const recipientPhone = testArguments.recipient || DEFAULT_RECIPIENT_PHONE;
  const verificationCode = testArguments.code || DEFAULT_VERIFICATION_CODE;

  const submitOtpResponse = await submitOtp(recipientPhone, verificationCode);
  if (!submitOtpResponse) {
    console.error('Otp submit failed');
    Deno.exit(1);
  }
  console.log('Otp Verification Successful');
}

Deno.test(submitOtpTest);

if (import.meta.main) {
  submitOtpTest();
}



Can you explain why you want to write a test against the Twilio API? Twilio's SLA guarantees a reliable uptime and even, in the unlikely case of a broken API, there's not much you can do to fix it besides opening a ticket.
If you really need this, I'd recommend to mock the API call. Here's an example on how to do it with jest. I don't know much about Deno but I assume there's a similar way.

I need to write the test so the QA team can easily test the api implementation. It would be ideal if they could run the test without manually changing variables since it'll be run before every deployment.

Mocking the API call is probably your best option then. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to do this in Deno but maybe this points you in the right direction
